# php/mysql responsive imaging

Tags: php, css, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive php/mysql image system. 
I took this Code from the internet:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="item-container">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="item-caption">
                    <div class="item-caption-inner">
                        <div class="item-caption-inner1">
                            <h3>$45</h3>
                            <span>Only</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/menu-1.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-container">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="item-caption">
                    <div class="item-caption-inner">
                        <div class="item-caption-inner1">
                            <h3>$45</h3>
                            <span>Only</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src="images/menu-5.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is showing this: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITO2T.png)

and tried to make it responsive with mysql and php. So I can add the images.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if($row['Ordine']  %2 != 0)
                {
                    echo "<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>";
                    }
        echo "
        <div class='item-container'>
            <a href='#'>
                <div class='item-caption'>
                    <div class='item-caption-inner'>
                        <div class='item-caption-inner1'>
                            <h3>$45</h3>
                            <span>Only</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img src='/dulcearoma/admin/images/" . $row["Poza"]. "' />
            </a>
            </div>";
            if($row['Ordine']  %2 != 0)
                {
                    echo "</div>";
                    }
    }   
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

but it's looking like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qntgW.png)

The Ordine row is 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

I'm really out of ideas

Comment: this is a CSS /styling issue

Comment: "this is a CSS /styling issue" Most likely to add to @FunkFortyNiner 's comment. You can use  display: inline-block and a  fixed width and height on your image (notice might cause out off scale problems).. So the images go to the next "row" if they does fit anymore and the images will get the same height.

Comment: How is your code more "responsive" than the original though?

Comment: each image needs to hold the same class, yours in the loop doesn't have that and it's next to impossible to know what class that should be. So you need to add that to `<img src='/dulcearoma/admin/images/" . $row["Poza"]. "' />`. Plus, each must have the same height and width. You can consider this as an answer here.

Comment: All photos have the same height and width.

Answer (score 0):

please use boostrap class="img-responsive" and add height and width in img tag

example :

```
 <img src="images/menu-5.jpg" class="img-responsive"  width="304" height="236">
```

Comment: Same. No difference